# Where's the extra space coming from in these images?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I've replicated in various browsers.

I have divs with images each in a wrapper http://jsfiddle.net/QnVYL/. The wrapper has a 1px border and 5px padding. The image inside is sized to 100% width.

For some reason, though, there is more than 5px between the bottom of the image and the bottom of its wrapper. See how the padding does appear to be equal on all sides of the images? There seem to be 3 pixels added from... somewhere. Firebug doesn't let me know where from.

How can I get rid of the space? I can't use absolute positioning to fake the padding because I'm not yet sure I'll always know the exact height of the image.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to reset the browser styles? Maybe something about the display attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known issue. Try:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: AHA! When the image is inline, the div wraps the text line's baseline! Eric Meyer writes about it here: http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2002/img-table/

Answer (score 5):

It's a line-height. Images are rendered as inline-block elements by default. The line-height makes sure that following text does not stick to the image like here:

```
<img...><br>foo
```

[image: line-height separates text from imag] [image: text sticking to image]

Both these fixes are useful, depending on the situation:

```
.imgContainer { line-height: 0; }

img { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. But when would line-height 0 suit me better? Do some browsers act oddly with block images or something?

Comment: In your particular situation, I guess it really doesn't make much of a difference. But suppose you want to add more content like some text or other images, then line-height may become useful. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mDP85/

Answer (score 3):

No extra spacing if you add `img {display:block}`

http://jsfiddle.net/lexy0202/uxMu9/2

Answer (score 1):

Like I guessed it is the display attribut:

```css
#container {
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```